# Last Date of Year in SSIS Derived Column as a Date type

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl, derived-column

I am creating a derived column in SSIS to pull last date of year for 2012. What would the expression look like?

`LastDateofYear` attribute in `date` data type

Answer (score 1):

Since always the last day is 31/12 then you can concatenate a string to the year part and convert it to `DT_DATE` data type using a derived column:

```
(DT_DATE)"2012-12-31"
```

If the year is a variable:

```
(DT_DATE)((DT_WSTR,10)@[User::year] + "-12-31")
```

Comment: Hi Hadi - the Derived Column Transformation Editor does not have the "DT_Date" expression available. Under Date/Time functions, I have DATEPART, YEAR, OR GETDATE available. Could one of those work?

Comment: @Starbrite420 dt_date is not a datetime function it is a data type cast function  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017